# cron job can not run laravel schedule on godaddy server

Tags: laravel, cron

I'm trying to build a laravel scheduler to save my data history. I create a command  "MisReportBackup". then I add it in the kernel too.

```
protected $commands = [
    '\App\Console\Commands\MisReportBackup',
];
```

my schedule function is

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
     $schedule->command('MisReportBackup:MisReport')->dailyAt('16:59');
}
```

then i create a cron job on server

```
59  16  *   *   *   cd /home/public_html/outpace-erp-v1.1 && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

it's 17:13:58(SGT) but did not work yet.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to specify the schedule for the cron job. For Laravel's scheduler to work, it has to run every minute.

```
* * * * php /home/public_html/outpace-erp-v1.1/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

See the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling).

Comment: thank you for your kind response. I am trying this way. but not work yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
*   *   *   *   *   /usr/local/bin/php /home/technolive/public_html/outpace-erp-v1.1/artisan schedule:run > /dev/null 2>&1
```

it's work.